# Converting binary IOstream into file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload

I am using rails server. i am sending core http request.
in request.body contents a file which I want to be uploaded.  This request.body is StringIo object.  I want to upload this file to my server.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  If you have some code you've written that you are trying to get to work, we'd sure like to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This writes the file to disk in 1mb (1024**2) chunks. Reading the whole file in at once can leave you open to a DOS with huge files.

```
File.open("where-you-want-the-file", "w") do |f|
  while blk = request.body.read(1024**2)
    f << blk
  end
end
```